# IntelliJ logs pa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl - EA-96451

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 2021.1 is throwing error visible in the log for an sql Repository Impl class containing jpa queries and hangs all opened IntelliJ project windows as soon as I start to edit any line. Even disabling the IntelliJ java sql libraries plugin and deselecting all sql validations in Settings doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Full stacktrace:

```
2022-09-29 13:18:21,739 [ 631550]  ERROR - pa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl - EA-96451
Details: Query:
select name as name, id as pkod, electric as electric, gas as gas, trader.code as trader, invoicingEmails as emails, concat(postCode,' ',city,' ',street) as addr,'' as mailAddr, taxRegNo as taxNr, vatRegNo as regNr, '' as legalRespres, '' as contactName,'' as contactTel, '' as contactEmail, '' as finContactName, '' as finContactTel,'' as finContactEmail, '' as fromApollo,'' as loginEmail,'' as emailApollo, '' as azon, code as custId, modifyDate as valtozott from Partner where trader.code=:trd and code is not null  and code in (select distinct code from GasContract EleContract where fromDate <= GETDATE() and toDate >= GETDATE() and traderCode = :trd) 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:559)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:281)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:226)
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.write(QuietWriter.java:48)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:317)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:322)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.error(IdeaLogger.java:103)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.lambda$static$0(QlReferenceImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache$PolyVariantResolver.resolve(ResolveCache.java:69)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolve$1(ResolveCache.java:154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Computable.get(Computable.java:17)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$loggingResolver$4(ResolveCache.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Computable.get(Computable.java:17)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolve(ResolveCache.java:238)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolve(ResolveCache.java:154)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:169)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:162)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.multiResolve(QlReferenceImpl.java:478)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlPsiImplUtil.resolve(QlPsiImplUtil.java:48)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceExpressionImpl.resolve(QlReferenceExpressionImpl.java:51)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.processQualifierExpression(QlReferenceImpl.java:210)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.processQualifierExpression(QlReferenceImpl.java:254)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.processResolveVariants(QlReferenceImpl.java:93)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.resolveInner(QlReferenceImpl.java:362)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.lambda$static$0(QlReferenceImpl.java:51)
```

the stacktrace keeps repeating from line

```
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache$PolyVariantResolver.resolve(ResolveCache.java:69)
```

Thanks

UPDATE
If I delete from the start of the select till the "from" keyword, the it' all ok, maybe the problem with too many columns or too long select?

UPDATE2
Tried with the newest intellij v 2022.2.2, in most part behaves exactly the same but it doesn't hang, not yet.
The differences are: the first line has changed to:

```
2022-10-03 09:57:51,088 [238177908] SEVERE - #c.i.j.q.p.i.QlReferenceImpl - EA-96451
```

The stackoverflowerror still remains but with different stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3954)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4789)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4734)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4732)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4732)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4698)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4820)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharPropertyGreedy.match(Pattern.java:4329)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4789)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4734)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4698)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4820)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3955)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharPropertyGreedy.match(Pattern.java:4329)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4789)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4734)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3955)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3608)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:772)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2746)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2671)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.IdeaLogRecordFormatter.format(IdeaLogRecordFormatter.java:37)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:199)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.RollingFileHandler.publish(RollingFileHandler.kt:57)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:980)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:1007)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1118)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.doLogError(IdeaLogger.java:166)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.error(IdeaLogger.java:142)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.lambda$static$0(QlReferenceImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache$PolyVariantResolver.resolve(ResolveCache.java:69)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolve$1(ResolveCache.java:154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Computable.get(Computable.java:16)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$loggingResolver$4(ResolveCache.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Computable.get(Computable.java:16)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolve(ResolveCache.java:238)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolve(ResolveCache.java:154)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:169)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:162)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.multiResolve(QlReferenceImpl.java:494)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlPsiImplUtil.resolve(QlPsiImplUtil.java:48)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceExpressionImpl.resolve(QlReferenceExpressionImpl.java:50)
    at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.processQualifierExpression(QlReferenceImpl.java:211)
at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.processResolveVariants(QlReferenceImpl.java:94)
at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.resolveInner(QlReferenceImpl.java:362)
at com.intellij.jpa.ql.psi.impl.QlReferenceImpl.lambda$static$0(QlReferenceImpl.java:52)
```

The last part is repeating from line

```
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache$PolyVariantResolver.resolve(ResolveCache.java:69)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Please check if the problem reproduces in the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) along with a [minimal reproducible project sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.